# gwtp can't deserialize response

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

Im grafting the code from the carstore example into my prototype app and having a strange problem.  I can't get the thing to deserialize the json response.

Heres the error:

```
com.gwtplatform.dispatch.shared.ActionException: Unable to deserialize response.
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.rest.RestResponseDeserializer.getDeserializedResponse(RestResponseDeserializer.java:60)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.rest.RestResponseDeserializer.deserialize(RestResponseDeserializer.java:38)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.rest.RestDispatchAsync$1.onResponseReceived(RestDispatchAsync.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor246.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONException: "[{"empno":0,"firstName":"Edith","lastName":"Fisher","reportsTo":0}]" represents invalid json data!
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.rest.JsonSerializer.deserialize(JsonSerializer.java:40)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.rest.RestResponseDeserializer.getDeserializedResponse(RestResponseDeserializer.java:58)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONException: "[{"empno":0,"firstName":"Edith","lastName":"Fisher","reportsTo":0}]" represents invalid json data!
    at name.pehl.piriti.json.client.AbstractJsonReader.read(AbstractJsonReader.java:226)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.client.rest.JsonSerializer.deserialize(JsonSerializer.java:37)
    ... 30 more
```

My service interface:

```
@Path(ResourcesPath.JACKSON)
public interface EmployeeService extends RestService {
    /**
     * calls the get employees service.
     * 
     * @param num
     * @return GetResults<Employee>
     */
    @GET
    Action<GetResults<Employee>> getEmployees(@QueryParam("num") Integer num);
}
```

The GetResults class:

```
public class GetResults<T extends Dto> implements Result {
    ArrayList<T> results;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected GetResults() {
    }

    public GetResults(ArrayList<T> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

the Dto class:

```
public interface Dto extends IsSerializable {
}
```

and my entity:

```
public class Employee implements Dto {

    public int empno;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String extension;
    public String eMail;
    public String officeCode;
    public int reportsTo;
    public String jobTitle;

    /**
     * The key provider that provides the unique ID of a contact.
     */
    public static final ProvidesKey<Employee> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<Employee>() {
        @Override
        public Object getKey(Employee item) {
            return item == null ? null : item.getEmpno();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Example of how to create an instance of a JsonEncoderDecoder for a data
     * transfer object.
     * 
     * public interface EmployeeJED extends JsonEncoderDecoder<Employee> {
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * @param empno
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @param extension
     * @param eMail
     * @param officeCode
     * @param reportsTo
     * @param jobTitle
     */
    public Employee(
            int empno,
            String firstName,
            String lastName,
            String extension,
            String eMail,
            String officeCode,
            int reportsTo,
            String jobTitle) {
        this.setEmpno(empno);
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setExtension(extension);
        this.seteMail(eMail);
        this.setOfficeCode(officeCode);
        this.setReportsTo(reportsTo);
        this.setJobTitle(jobTitle);
    }

    public Employee(int empno, String firstName, String lastName, int reportsTo) {
        this.setEmpno(empno);
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setReportsTo(reportsTo);
    }
```

and for good measure, my caller from the presenter

```
@Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        // ActionBarVisibilityEvent.fire(this, true);
        // ChangeActionBarEvent.fire(this, Arrays.asList(ActionType.ADD), true);

        dispatcher.execute(employeeService.getEmployees(1), new AbstractAsyncCallback<GetResults<Employee>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GetResults<Employee> result) {
                getView().displaySearchGrid(result.getResults());
            }
        });

    }
```

and my module file:

```
<module rename-to='gwtptabsample'>
    <!-- Inherit rest dispatch stuff. Order matters here, rest needs to be before mvp -->
    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.dispatch.DispatchRest" />
    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithEntryPoint" />

    <!-- GinUiBinder allows injecting widgets in UiBinder -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.GinUiBinder" />

    <!-- debugging
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value=INFO/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/> -->

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. You can change -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark" />



    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path="client" />
    <source path="shared"/>

    <extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules"
        value="com.gwtplatform.samples.tab.client.gin.ClientModule" />

    <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.extensions"
        value="com.gwtplatform.samples.tab.client.gin.GinjectorExtension" />
</module>
```

The number in the parameter is just telling my service how many random employees to generate.  I get the same error if i call one result or multiple.  Again, this is based on the model that is used in the CarStore example in the GWTP source tree.  Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Looking here https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/blob/master/gwtp-carstore/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/carstore/client/rest/RatingService.java, I'm seeing that you might use RestAction instead of Action. Also, DTOs in com.gwtplatform.carstore.shared.dto all have a no-args constructor (this might be required by the deserialization process)

Comment: Well, its a start, the problem is that code isn't even in the snapshot yet.  I just pulled the code and tried to compile it because they changed the RestAction object and the rest project is broken and won't compile.  And I have no parameter constructors as well.  I just didn't paste them here apparently.

Comment: Just FYI: There's a big api change in the rest dispatcher that is coming in really shortly, a lot more stable than the experimental stuff you're using right now :D

Oh and SP is right, serializable objects must always have an empty CTOR.

Comment: Yea, im looking at the code you merged in 5 or so days ago.  It looks good, I like what your doing, but your using <X> X in a few places as your returns, which won't compile on JDK 6.  And I'm bound by company policy to never acknowledge that JDK 7 was released.  I guess I will go back to playing with Resty-GWT as this needs to be done today.